# register_activation_hook not creating table

Tags: plugins, customization

As my question is duplicate, I am still stuck in my code, and no solution has been found.

I create a function in the plugin to create a table after activating the plugin. But the table is not created after activating the plugin. I have placed this code in the main file of my plugin.

Please overlook my code :

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'like_dislike_counter_install');

function like_dislike_counter_install() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'subpostvotingcount';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
          sno int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          postid int(50) NOT NULL,
          subpostid varchar(5) NOT NULL,
          votingcount varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          postclicktime timestamp(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        )  $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create auto column `sno int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,` and forget to define it as key, add `PRIMARY KEY (sno)` to your sql.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      sno int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      postid int(50) NOT NULL,
      subpostid varchar(5) NOT NULL,
      votingcount varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      postclicktime timestamp(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (sno)
    )  $charset_collate;";
```

If still won't work, try replace `postclicktime timestamp(5)`  with `postclicktime timestamp`. 
[Before MySQL 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html), MySQL did not support fractional seconds stored as part of a TIMESTAMP datatype.

Comment: I added  PRIMARY KEY (sno) and replaced postclicktime timestamp, But still table is not creating.
Shall i again upload the plugin and activate it?

Comment: Update plugin (just the changed file), deactivate it and then activate. @PuspalataPanigrahi

Comment: I removed the plugin and again uploaded & activate it, But still the table not created in my Database.

Comment: Any error message? Do you have `debug` enabled? If not then add `define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE); define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', TRUE);` to `wp-config.php`, again try to activate the plugin and check error in log file (`wp-content/debug.log`). @PuspalataPanigrahi

Comment: Below error is showing :

The plugin generated 386 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Comment: Check error message in `wp-content/debug.log` file or add `exit()` after `dbDelta( $sql );`. @PuspalataPanigrahi

Comment: Yes now its working...

Comment: Remember to disable `debug` on production. @PuspalataPanigrahi

Comment: If it was a sql problem and the [answer was helpful](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), can you?  @PuspalataPanigrahi

Comment: Yes it was a sql problem. Actually i forgot to add comma in the below line :
postclicktime timestamp  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP